# Fixing SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql

The connection to the MySQL server is not made even if the authentication is correct, and this is my code to connect to database:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Core;


use PDO;
use PDOException;

class Db extends PDO
{
    
    private static $instance;

    private const DBHOST = 'localhost';
    private const DBUSER = 'user';
    private const DBPASS = 'passe';
    private const DBNAME = 'bloghkjw_dbname';



    private function __construct()
    {
        
        // DSN de connexion
        $_dsn = 'mysql:dbname='. self::DBNAME . ';host=' . self::DBHOST;

       
        try{
            parent::__construct($_dsn, self::DBUSER, self::DBPASS);

            $this->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES utf8');
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
            //var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
    }


    public static function getInstance():self
    {
        if(self::$instance === null){
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }


    public function __destruct()
    {
       
    }

}
```

Comment: `even if the authentication is correct,`...the authentication is **not** correct. That's what the error is telling you. It cannot lie. Check how the user is configured on that mySQL instance, and ensure it's set to allow a login from localhost, and ensure you've definitely got the password right. We can't see your database so we don't know what the correct setup is.

Comment: locally works well but when I host it I got the error

Comment: are you shure thaht the local mysql and zje remote mysql have the same credentials same username password

Comment: `when I host it I got the error`...that's why you need to double check what the mySQL user's configuration actually is on the hosted server. Clearly you made a mistake somewhere